# How to embed an Apache Superset dashboard in a webpage?

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to implement the Apache superset dashboard in a webpage.
Anyone have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: This question needs more information. What kind of webpage? Just HTML? Do we have JavaScript? Is it powered on the server-side by C#? PHP? JS?

Answer (score 12):

Keep the iframe tag line as you mentioned.

```
<iframe src="linkToYourDashBoard?standalone=true"></iframe>
```

and check the `superset_config.py` file.

```
HTTP_HEADERS = {'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN'}
```

Change the line to

```
HTTP_HEADERS = {'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOWALL'}
```

or

```
HTTP_HEADERS = {}
```

Don't forget to add `superset_config.py` file to your python path.

Comment: I want to add authentication and authorization in the webpage.Can i able to do that ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Follow the documentation <https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html>

Comment: As of at least 2.0.0, Superset now also supports `?standalone=` values of `0, 1, 2, 3` with more granularity in terms of what's hidden compared to just `true`.  See https://superset.apache.org/docs/creating-charts-dashboards/creating-your-first-dashboard/.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to update the public roles with these options.

- Security/List Roles:
- can explore json on Superset,
- can dashboard on Superset,
- all database access on all_database_access

Second, embed your dashboard in your HTML

```
<iframe src="localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/5/?standalone=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: could you please explain in more details.(if you have any screenshot,this would really help)

Comment: when i am running this HTML its not working <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

   <iframe
   src= "localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/5/?preselect_filters=%7B%2248%22%3A%7B%22Retailer_country%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Quarter%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Product%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7Dstandalone=true"
   width="600"
   height="400"
   seamless frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">
 </iframe>
 <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>

Comment: try using <embed> tag

<embed src="http://www.w3schools.com" height="300" width="300" />

Comment: http://localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/5/?preselect_filters=%7B%2248%22%3A%7B%22Retailer_country%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Quarter%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Product%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D      this is my dashboard URL,am i doing anything wrong with html ?

Comment: try [link](http://localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/5/?standalone=true&preselect_filters=%7B%2235%22%3A%7B%22Retailer_country%22%3A%5B%22Quarter%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Product%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D)  you need the `standalone=true`

Comment: I tried the link you suggested but still not working in chrome or firefox.

Comment: here is the html code        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/5/?standalone=true&preselect_filters=%7B%2235%22%3A%7B%22Retailer_country%22%3A%5B%22Quarter%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22Product%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%7D"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

Comment: can we implement the webpage through flask ? @emacip #superset #apache-superset

Comment: I dont think so @Ankita its very clear [documentation](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/security.html)

Comment: http://10.85.150.139/r/5 this is my dashboard url which is in aws ..whenever i am trying to use this link in iframe tag it is not working whenever i am trying to add in hyperlink it is working @emacip

Answer (score 4):

[Superset Embedded SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk) allows you to embed
dashboards from Superset into your own app, using your app's authentication.

1. superset backend server: update `superset_config.py` or `config.py`

```py
FEATURE_FLAGS =  {
  "EMBEDDED_SUPERSET": True, # requirement
}
"GUEST_ROLE_NAME": "Public", # you might need to edit role permissions when 403 error
"GUEST_TOKEN_JWT_EXP_SECONDS": 300  # 5 minutes, or you could set it longer
```

2. your app's backend server

- fetch access_token

  - http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/login
- fetch guest_token

  - http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/guest_token/

3. your app's frontend, for example:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk"></script>
<script>
    supersetEmbeddedSdk.embedDashboard({
      id: 'd3918020-0349-435d-9277-xxxxxx', // given by the Superset embedding UI
      supersetDomain: 'http://localhost:9000',
      mountPoint: document.getElementById('container'), // any html element that can contain an iframe
      fetchGuestToken: () =>
        'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.xxxxxx.1RExnlLfdDI6P4vG3gB0otLL7XR_3OE2OZ0WhCKyTyE', // guest_token
      dashboardUiConfig: {} // dashboard UI config: hideTitle, hideTab, hideChartControls (optional)
    })
  </script>
```

Please refer to: [Embedding Superset dashboards in your React application](https://medium.com/@khushbu.adav/embedding-superset-dashboards-in-your-react-application-7f282e3dbd88)

Answer (score 0):

Superset now provides the [Superset Embedded SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk), an NPM package for inserting an iframe that will embed your Superset dashboard.  I'm using it at the moment and it is relatively straightforward; this is the current implementation example provided in the docs:

```
import { embedDashboard } from "@superset-ui/embedded-sdk";

embedDashboard({
  id: "abc123", // given by the Superset embedding UI
  supersetDomain: "https://superset.example.com",
  mountPoint: document.getElementById("my-superset-container"), // any html element that can contain an iframe
  fetchGuestToken: () => fetchGuestTokenFromBackend(),
  dashboardUiConfig: { hideTitle: true }, // dashboard UI config: hideTitle, hideTab, hideChartControls (optional)
});
```

Obviously the end result could still be achieved by adding the iframe "manually," but using the official abstraction might provide simplicity and future functionality in subsequent versions.