# Is it possible to embed VM local sever apache superset into Cpanel using flask app?

Tags: python, flask, virtual-machine, cpanel, apache-superset

I was wondering if i can embed apache superset dashboard from VM local server in cpanel flask app? Is it possible from VM to cpanel flask app? I would like to show embedded superset to my cpanel subdomain

I tried to find some documentation, but unfortunately i did not find one. Please help me if you guys find one whether its in other language or english

Comment: You can try to embed an Apache Superset dashboard from a VM into a cPanel-hosted Flask app, usually by using iframes or API integration within your Flask application.

Comment: I did try but its not working, but i dont know about the API integration, would you mind telling me more about it?

Comment: https://superset.apache.org/docs/contributing/local-backend/ explains how to configure the server, and with it, you can render it with flask.

Comment: Also, the answer is already posted on here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542594/how-can-i-embed-superset-apache-into-flask-web-app?rq=2