# How to embed/use graph generated by apache superset directly in other web application

Tags: apache-superset

I have my own web applications and need to implement reporting in it.
So I want to know how can we embed the graph generated by apache superset in my web application/project ?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [Apache superset dashboard in webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219101/apache-superset-dashboard-in-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Answer:**

You can insert it with an HTML IFrame tag.
For example if the Url of your dashborad is

> http://52.59.247.208:8088/superset/dashboard/1/

[image]

Add simply the following suffix "?standalone=true" and add it in your HTML code like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Charts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testing IFrame</h1>
    <iframe
      width=100%
      height=100%
      frameBorder="0"
      src="http://52.59.247.208:8088/superset/dashboard/1/?standalone=true"
    >
    </iframe>
</body>
```

But first you have to edit your superset_config.py file by adding following line, if you want to use it without any problems:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE="None"
```

Comment: I added the `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE="None"` but it still redirect me to the login form!